# Align google table chart column heading, values to same side using chart options

Tags: google-visualization

In google table chart, I would like to align chart column heading and values to the same side, both on to right/center/left. Is there any way out to accomplish this using only chart options. Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use config option --> `cssClassNames`

define a class for --> `headerCell`

```
cssClassNames: {
  headerCell: 'customHeader'
}
```

then add css to the page to align the cells...

```
.customHeader {
  text-align: center;
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
    ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
    ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
    ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  table.draw(data, {
    cssClassNames: {
      headerCell: 'customHeader'
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.customHeader {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that piece of code. But, I would like to know is there any way to do using "Configuration Options"

Comment: `cssClassNames` is from the config options